# I can't call div with dynamic id

Tags: javascript

My code is:

```
<div id="slider">
```

This is the main div:

```
    <div id="mainNews">
      <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
          <div class="newsInfo" id="news"& element style=" display:block"></div>
        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:Repeater>            
    </div>             
  </div>    
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/FirstSlider.js"></script>
```

The JavaScript is:

```
var sliderTimeoutID;
var element = 1;

function delayedSlider() {
  element == 5 ? element = 1 : element = element;
  element == 1 ? pElement = 4 : pElement = element - 1;
  document.getElementById("news" + pElement).style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("news" + element).style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("newsLink" + pElement).className = "newsLinks";
  document.getElementById("newsLink" + element).className = "newsLinks selected";
  sliderTimeoutID = window.setTimeout(delayedSlider, 6000);
  element++;
}

delayedSlider();
```

How can I call the incremental id?

Comment: how to call my function in div to increment id

Comment: `<div class="newsInfo" id="news"& element` would appear to not be valid HTML nor Razor. I'd suggest you inspect the DOM to see what the actual `id` values are in the output.

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54149100/edit) then create a `[<>]` snippet to show a [mcve] WITHOUT ASP since your ASP is likely not relevant once you solve the illegal HTML created by `id="news"& element` . Please show actual HTML and remember IDs must be unique. Also you have no var called pElement

Comment: Also note that nothing about this is jQuery. I've amended the title and retagged the question for you

Comment: id="news"& element  not work

Comment: asp is appeared but id not incremented

Comment: function showSlide(num) {
    window.clearTimeout(sliderTimeoutID);
    document.getElementById("news1").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("news2").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("news3").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("news4").style.display = "none";